# How do I update a MySQL table with datagrid view (Winforms, C#)?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm very new to C# (and coding in general), and have had trouble piecing together the answers to similar questions posted here already.

I'm working on a winforms C# program in Visual Studio 2017. The goal is to view a set portion of a MySQL table in a Data Grid, to edit any values visible, and then to update changes in the table upon hitting a button.

I've managed to connect to a local MySQL server, and show the existing data in a datagrid view (depending on the particular SQL query entered):

```
//TITLE QUERY
public void runTitleQuery()
{

        string MySQLConnectionString = "datasource=10.1.1.110;port=3306;username=operator;password=;database=cortex;SslMode=none";
        MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(MySQLConnectionString);

        string TitleSearch = "SELECT * FROM titles WHERE TITLE_NO = @TenementNumber";

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(TitleSearch, databaseConnection);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;

            databaseConnection.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);


            MySqlParameter TenNo = new MySqlParameter();
            TenNo.ParameterName = "@TenementNumber";
            TenNo.Value = textboxSearchByTitle.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(@TenNo);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            SurfaceTable.DataSource = dt;
            databaseConnection.CloseAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Query failed" + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

So far so good.

I'm now trying to allow editing of data (including adding a new row if possible). Edits would be sent to the server upon hitting a button outside the table.

Where I think I'm going wrong is somewhere between bound and unbound grids, and SQL connections (which I still don't grasp fully).

Each entry in the table has a unique identifier (column is called TAS_ID).

My first attempt is to do something along these lines:

```
//Write table to server button
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string SQLCommandString = "UPDATE Tenements WHERE TAS_ID='@TASID'";

        try
            {
            //set string  
            string MySQLConnectionString = "datasource=10.1.1.110;username=operator;password=;database=cortex;SslMode=none";
            MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(MySQLConnectionString);

            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(SQLCommandString, databaseConnection);
            cmd2.CommandTimeout = 60;

            //Create parameters

            MySqlDataReader MyReader2;

            MyReader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
            while (MyReader2.Read())
            {
            }
            databaseConnection.CloseAsync();

        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

However as you can see, I don't know how to update the row with the new data. I attempt to create parameters relating to each column, but I have a feeling that's not the right way to do it.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Please let me know if any further information is required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to demonstrate you way for updating. you want to change all record and then save them or you want to save each cell update after editing

however your mistakes are :

1.you have not fill your parameters ( use ParameterInfo in your code and add it to your command)

2.update statement must be like this

```
update your_table set field_name = @value where identity_filed = @Identity_filed_value
```

Comment: Thanks Alireza,
I want the user to be able to change the whole row, or multiple rows of data and all of those changes to be saved only once the button is pressed.

I started to put the parameters in and wasn't sure which value to set the parameter with - isn't that what the string does?
UPDATE Tenements SET TITLE_CODE=@titlecode, TITLE_NO=@titleno, WHERE TAS_ID='@TASID'";


                //Create parameters
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titlecode", <what goes here?>);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titleno", <what goes here?>);

Comment: with method dataGridView cell_Changed you can detect which are rows changed and when use clicked on save button you have your changed rows and in row you have your identifier and all cells . with update statement you can update value of your changed rows

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code, I think your Data Grid is showing data of 'titles' table and you are trying to update other table 'Tenements'

If your table has Primary key, you can go for MySqlCommandBuilder.
following link can be helpful for you

http://www.mysqlab.net/knowledge/kb/detail/topic/c%23/id/4922

Answer (score 0):

Here is the format you should be using. FYI the parameters are for preventing SQL injection.

```
void UpdateEntry()
    {
        string sqlstring = "ConnectionDetails";
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(sqlstring))
        {
            var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TASID","Your TASID Data Dude");
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Tenements WHERE TAS_ID='@TASID'";
        }


    }
```

Now what you really probably want to be doing is keeping track of the new entries and passing their data to the Update Function that contains a loop that updates the command for each entry like so.

```
 public struct UpdateItems
    {
       public string FirstName;
       public string LastName;
       public string Age;

    }

void UpdateEntry(List<UpdateItems>Items)
    {
        string TableName = "SQLTableName";
        string sqlstring = "ConnectionDetails";
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(sqlstring))
        {
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                foreach (var item in Items)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName",item.FirstName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName",item.LastName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age",item.Age);
                    cmd.CommandText = $"Insert Into {TableName} Values (@FirstName, @LastName , @Age)";
                }
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //Do some checking
                    throw;
                }

            }        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your help. I'll try this out and will update with the results.

Much appreciated!